# How to Route to specific pages based on id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In one of my React projects, I have two components PhotoComp and VideoComp. I call both components based on following API -> /content/list/abc123ghi for VideoComp and /content/list/pqr456yui for PhotoComp. Now my Routing in App.js is as follows

```
<Route path="/content/list/:videoId" component={VideoComp} />
<Route path="/content/list/:photoId" component={PhotoComp} />
```

Now in Video and Photo components, I extract the parameter using useParams(), and then it's expected to route based on parameter. When I click on the Video section on the Main page it redirects to VideoComp perfectly showing video id 'abc123ghi' above in URL whereas when clicked on the Photo section it doesn't redirect to PhotoComp it moves to VideoComp, but, URL shown above is with photo id 'pqr456yui'.

What could be the appropriate solution?

Answer (score 3):

If they are in a switch this is because your two routes are exactly the same /content/list/pqr456yui could refer to both Video and Photo. The only difference would be the property of useParams to get the id. `const {videoId} = useParams() vs const {photoId} = useParams()` being used.
You need some way to differentiante between them.
e.g. changing the url path

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/videos/list/:videoId" component={VideoComp} />
    <Route path="/photos/list/:photoId" component={PhotoComp} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Yes right... but, how can we switch between two components?

Comment: What do you mean with switch. For my example /videos/list/abc123ghi would render VideoComp and /photos/list/pqr456yui would render PhotoComp

Comment: Where shall I use props.match.params?

Comment: Sorry will edit that. You can use useParams instead of props.match.params

Comment: Even I had done the same way but, still getting error and its routing to Video Section only. URL I am getting perfectly but, its not routing to desired component

Comment: Hmm you will have to provide the error and updated app route to be able to help

Comment: Make sure you have updated the path to as I have in <Route>

Answer (score 1):

React Router doesn't actually know whether you are passing a videoId or a photoId as your parameters. It tries to match the URL and returns the first match that it found which is VideoComp.

You need some way to differentiate between your video and photo ids. One thing that I would suggest is to wrap your VideoComp and PhotoComp in another component and conditionally render in that component.

Here is an example:

```
<Route path="/content/list/:videoId" component={PhotoVideoComp} />
```

PhotoVideoComp would look like this:

```
    function PhotoVideoComp(){
    return(
       props.match.params.videoId === 'video' ? VideoComp:PhotoComp
    )
    
    }
  export default PhotoVideoComp
```